# Parameter '_IDFID' not found in the collection (C# + MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql

Lately i found an error and i couldn't fix it, even tried to change the parameter but didn't help in anything..
Here's the error which i face,

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Parameter '_IDFID' not found in the collection.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.GetParameterFlexible(String parameterName, Boolean throwOnNotFound)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetAndFixParameter(String spName, MySqlSchemaRow param, Boolean realAsFloat, MySqlParameter returnParameter)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Testme.Form3.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Modather\source\repos\Testme\Testme\Form3.cs:line 35
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I really don't know where's the problem, but here's my Saved Procedures from MySQL

```
CREATE DEFINER=`sql7258326`@`%` PROCEDURE `MemberEditORAdd`(
_IDFID int,
MemberName varchar(45),
MemberRank varchar(45),
MemberWarn varchar(45),
MemberJoinDate varchar(45)
)
BEGIN
        IF IDFID = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO KODCP (IDFID,MEMBRNAME,MEMBRRANK,MEMBRWARN,MJOINDATE)
            VALUES (_IDFID,MemberName,MemberRank,MemberWarn,MemberJoinDate);

        ELSE
            UPDATE KODCP
            SET
                MEMBRNAME = MemberName,
                MEMBRRANK = MemberRank,
                MEMBRWARN = MemberWarn,
                MJOINDATE = MemberJoinDate
            WHERE IDFNUB = _IDFID;
        END IF;

END
```

And the CODE which written in the VB that calls the above code is,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("MemberEditORAdd",mysqlCon);
                mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDFID", IDFID);
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRNAME", MemberName.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRRANK", MemberRank.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRWARN", MemberWarn.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MJOINDATE", MemberJoinDate.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Done!");
            }
        }
```

Thanks for attention and I hope you can help me fixing it, I will be so thankful for who help me to fix it <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `CREATE DEFINER='sql7258326'@'%' PROCEDURE 'MemberEditORAdd'(
>   _IDFID int,***`

You have created your procedure as above, and yet you are trying to use it as below

> `mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDFID", IDFID);`

You need to change you call to the method using the correct variable name, as in `mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_IDFID", IDFID);`

There is also no Procedure parameter called IDFID for this line

> `IF IDFID = 0 THEN`

The following code is run against the database:

```
    IF IDFID = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO KODCP (IDFID,MEMBRNAME,MEMBRRANK,MEMBRWARN,MJOINDATE)
        VALUES (_IDFID,MemberName,MemberRank,MemberWarn,MemberJoinDate);

    ELSE
        UPDATE KODCP
        SET
            MEMBRNAME = MemberName,
            MEMBRRANK = MemberRank,
            MEMBRWARN = MemberWarn,
            MJOINDATE = MemberJoinDate
        WHERE IDFNUB = _IDFID;
    END IF;
```

END

It says, `INSERT INTO KODCP (IDFID, MEMBRNAME, MEMBRRANK, MEMBRWARN, MJOINDATE)`, which means 
Insert values into the columns named `IDFID, MEMBRNAME, MEMBRRANK, MEMBRWARN, MJOINDATE` within the table called `KODCP`

It also says to supply the value for those parameters respectively from the following list of variables

`_IDFID, MemberName, MemberRank, MemberWarn, MemberJoinDate`

This means that the variables pased in to the procedure must be `_IDFID, MemberName, MemberRank, MemberWarn, MemberJoinDate`

This code:

```
using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("MemberEditORAdd",mysqlCon);
                mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDFID", IDFID);
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRNAME", MemberName.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRRANK", MemberRank.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MEMBRWARN", MemberWarn.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MJOINDATE", MemberJoinDate.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Done!");
            }
```

Should be replaced with this code:

```
using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("MemberEditORAdd",mysqlCon);
                mysqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_IDFID", IDFID);
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MemberName", MemberName.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MemberRank", MemberRank.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MemberWarn", MemberWarn.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MemberJoinDate", MemberJoinDate.Text.Trim());
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Operation Done!");
            }
```

And your check must be changed to

```
IF _IDFID = 0 THEN
```

Comment: I did it but got another error related to the same codes which "parameter 'MemberName' not found in the collection"

Comment: @MethoYehia: that's because you've mistyped the other parameter names.  Your procedure parameters are named `MemberName`, `MemberRank`, `MemberWarn` and `MemberJoinDate`, not `MEMBRNAME`, `MEMBRRANK`, `MEMBRWARN` and `MJOINDATE` as you've written them in your C# code.

Comment: @LukeWoodward; he's trying to bind everything to non-existent parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked now fine <3, I'm still learning so hope me a good luck xd